# Given a Boolean formula, does there exist a small circuit that computes a satisfying assignment?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, circuit-complexity, sat, parameterized-complexity, fine-grained

The 3-SAT problem can be defined as follows:

> **3-SAT**
>
> Input: A 3-CNF formula $\phi$ of size $m$ with $n$ variables.
>
> Question: Does there exist a variable assignment that satisfies $\phi$?

Consider the following parameterized problem that is a variantion of 3-SAT:

> **CVA:** Compressed variable assignment problem
>
> Input: A number $k$ and a 3-CNF formula $\phi$ of size $m$ with $n$ variables.
>
> Question: Does there exist a circuit $C$ of size at most $k\log(n)$ that computes a variable assignment that satisfies $\phi$?

**Note:** By circuit size, I mean the number of bits in the circuit's binary encoding where the circuits have bounded fan-in.

Below I will share some questions and results about the CVA problem.

**Question 1:** Do you happen to have any references to this problem or know of any related variants of SAT?

**Question 2:** How quickly can we solve the CVA problem in terms of parameters $m$, $n$, and $k$?

> The brute force approach for solving this problem is to enumerate all
>   circuits of size $k\log(n)$ and compute their corresponding
>   assignments.  For each assignment, we check if it satisfies $\phi$. 
>   This should take roughly $m \cdot n^k \cdot k\log(n)$ time.

**Question 3:** What is the parameterized complexity of this problem?  How does it relate to other parameterized problems, the $W$ hierarchy, and other complexity classes?

> It's worth noticing that the CVA problem is harder than a
>   variation of the minimum circuit size problem found here:
>   [Parameterized complexity of deciding if a string can be computed by circuits of size $k\log(n)$](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/37734/parameterized-complexity-of-deciding-if-a-string-can-be-computed-by-circuits-of)
>
> In particular, given a number $k$ and a bit string $x$, we can build a
>   trivial 1-SAT formula $\phi$ that is only satisfied by $x$.  Then, $x$
>   can be computed by a circuit of size $k\log(n)$ if and only if $\phi$
>   has a satisfying assignment that can be computed by a circuit of size
>   at most $k \log(n)$.

**Question 4:** Does looking at compressible satisfying assignments have any practical significance?  Has anyone ever measured the compression ratio of satisfying assignments for a collection of SAT instances that have come up in practice?

Comment: I didn't clarify what I mean by a circuit computing a variable assignment.  Assuming that the variables are ordered $v_1$, $v_2$, $v_3$, etc.  We can use the ordering to encode a variable assignment by a bit string.  Then, a circuit computing this bit string is what I meant by a circuit computing a variable assignment.  See here for a definition of what it means for a circuit to compute a bit string: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/37734/parameterized-complexity-of-deciding-if-a-string-can-be-computed-by-circuits-of

Comment: I could be mistaken, but I think I recall that this paper might talk about witness compression so it might have some relevance: "Infeasibility of instance compression and succinct PCPs for NP"

Comment: Note that to encode a circuit of size $s$ you need $\Theta(s \log s)$ bits, in the usual interpretation of "circuit of size $s$". So it's not $n^k$ to search over all circuits of size $k \log n$, it's more like $n^{k \log log n}$

Comment: @RyanWilliams Yes, thank you for bringing up that there are multiple notions of circuit size.  By size, I mean the number of bits in a binary encoding of the circuit.  This notion was referred to as "bit size" in the comments here: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/37734/parameterized-complexity-of-deciding-if-a-string-can-be-computed-by-circuits-of

Comment: I removed the ETH hardness remark because I am no longer convinced that it is correct.  I will ponder this and follow up tomorrow.  :)

Comment: If you have only (k\*log(n))/(3\*log(k\*log(n)) gates, then each gate needs at most 2\*log(k\*log(n)) bits, so the circuit description will fit into k*log(n) bits. ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer Thank you very much for the kind comment!!  Yes, if each gate has fanin two, then this makes sense.

Comment: @D.W. Thank you very much for the kind comment!!  I'm sometimes confused about what is the best way to notationally represent parameterized problems and their fixed levels.  Let me explain.  Often a parameterized problem is a decision problem along with a function that represents a parameter.  This function takes in an input instance and outputs a number.  Sometimes I want to say 2-CVA where I am not referring to the parameterized problem, but rather to the decision problem expressed as a fixed level of the parameterized problem.  Alternatively, sometimes, I want to express...

Comment: a decision problem along with a different function.  For example, I may informally write k^2-CVA to denote the compressed variable assignment problem along with a function that takes an instance, extracts the number k and squares it.  This informal notation that I used causes ambiguity because what if k were a variable representing a number.  Then, you may think I mean the decision problem (not parameterized problem) that is the fixed level k^2.

Comment: @RickyDemer Thank you again for your comment as well.  I decided to edit the question to bounded fan-in circuits.  This allows for a more convenient and seemingly intuitive bit encoding where the encoding roughly consists of a list of gates where each gate has a type and a fixed size list of inputs or gates that feed into it.

Comment: The alternative would be for each gate $g$ you have roughly log(n) bits where each of these bits is assigned to an input or gate and this bit represents whether or not that input or gate feeds into $g$.

Comment: @D.W. Thank you again.  I really appreciate it!!  I editted the question to resolve this issue.

Comment: Small comment: If we modify the problem so that the input is a Boolean formula (no restriction on it being 3-CNF), then I think we can show that the new problem is hard for every level of the W hierarchy.  If there is no progress on the 3-CNF case, then I might write this case up at some point.

Comment: Thinking more about this, I suspect that the problem above is $M[1]$-hard (or hard in a similar way).  I say this, because I think we can reduce from 3-SAT on formulas with $k \log n$ variables and $n$ clauses to the problem above.